# Angularjs : disable tab key default behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am developping a table of inputs.
What I want is : when use presses **'+' key** (wherever the cursor is in the table row), the app adds a new line in the table.
It works fine doing this :

```
<tr ng-repeat="sell in sells"  ng-keypress="newLine($event)">
```

My problem is that when user presses **tab key** in an input of the row to go to next input, the next input value is **highlighted** (which is the normal behaviour of tab key).
Then if user presses **'+'** to add a new line, it replaces the value of the input by the '+' sign.

I have set up a directive to allow user only to type number in the inputs, but it doesnt work when the input value is highlighted.

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('numbersOnly', function($timeout) {
   return {
     require: 'ngModel',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
       modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
           // this next if is necessary for when using ng-required on your input. 
           // In such cases, when a letter is typed first, this parser will be called
           // again, and the 2nd time, the value will be undefined
           if (inputValue == undefined) return '' 
           var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g, ''); 
           if (transformedInput!=inputValue) {
              modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
              modelCtrl.$render();
           }         

           return transformedInput;         
       });
     }
   };
});

<td style="width:59px"><input type="text" ng-model="sell.quantity" numbers-only enter-as-tab ></td>
```

If someone knows a way to prevent user from replacing highlighted value by the '+'.... or to disable the default behaviour of tab key.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you use `<input type="number" />` instead of `var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g, '');` ?

Comment: the problem with type number is the same, if the value is highlighted, to press '+' puts an empty value in the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the default action of the '+' key using a custom directive.

```
module.directive('overridePlusKey', ['$window', function ($window) {
    // Linker function
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('keydown', function (e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
        console.log(keyCode);
        if (keyCode == 107 || keyCode == 187)
        {
          e.preventDefault();
          // Your code here to add a row
        }
      });
    };
  }]);
```

Then apply it to the inputs like so:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="content" override-plus-key />
```

[See here for an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kpuclb3wAVP0laXAWKEr?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

This might be better done using form validation or even an `ng-change` handler, but if you prefer to stick to your existing `$parser` method you can revert to the original value using `$modelValue`:

```js
angular.module('myapp', []).directive('numbersOnly', function($timeout) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
      modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(inputValue) {
        if (inputValue == undefined) return '';
        var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g, '');
        if (transformedInput != inputValue) {
          modelCtrl.$setViewValue(modelCtrl.$modelValue);
          modelCtrl.$render();
          if (inputValue.indexOf('+') > -1) {
            alert("Perhaps trigger your newLine() here");
          }
          return modelCtrl.$modelValue;
        } else {
          return inputValue;
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <input type="text" ng-model="sell.quantity" numbers-only enter-as-tab>
</div>
```

Please don't try to disable the tab key.  Accessibility matters. (So does the user expectation that the tab key will do what the tab key normally does.)