# AngularJS way to disable a key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, keyboard, backspace

In my AngularJs project I want to disable the backspace key for all views. Here is an easy jQuery solution. Is there any solution for this written in AngularJs?

```
$(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.which === 8 && !$(e.target).is("input, textarea")) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable the backspace key for the entire website you can use something similar to this ([Angularjs : disable tab key default behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34879277/angularjs-disable-tab-key-default-behaviour)) and apply the directive to the body document using the `$document`.

Something like this:

```
angular.module('app', []).directive('muteKey', ['$document', function($document) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    $document.on("keydown", function(e) {
     /*
      * you don't need the $(e.target) if you want to
      * disable the key press in any place of the project
      * and not just for inputs or textareas
      */
      if (e.which === 8) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  };
}]);

<body mute-key>
    <!---->
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add an `ng-keydown` attribute to your `<input`> tag:

```
<input type="text" ng-keydown="checkKey($event)"/>

$scope.checkKey(keyEvent) {
    if (keyEvent.which === 13) { 
        $event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But I want to disable the key for the entire window

Answer (score 1):

Use the [$document Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$document)

```
$document.on("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.which === 8 && !$(e.target).is("input, textarea")) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

The [$document service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$document) has methods which are a [subset of jQuery called jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angularjs-s-jqlite).

---

> How can apply this code? My starting app is like `angular.module("my_app", ['ngRoute']);`

Put it in a run block:

```
angular.module("my_app").run(function($document) {

    $document.on("keydown", function keydown Handler(e) {
        //Put handler code here
    });

});
```

---

```
!$(e.target).is("input, textarea")
```

Can be translated:

```
(e.target.type == "input") || (e.target.type == "textarea");
```

Comment: How can apply this code? My starting app is like  angular.module("my_app", ['ngRoute']);